# If it is given that $\frac{\log x}{\log y }=3/4$, can I write $\log_y x=3/4$?

Tags: logarithms

Change of base formula:

$$ \log_b x = \frac{\log_a x}{\log_a b}$$

So if it is given that $\frac{\log x}{\log y }=3/4$

Can I write $\log_y x=3/4$?

Comment: yes you can write that

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Its given that Log x/ log y =log 4/log 3  so logy X= log3 4 and then can I conclude that y=3 and X=4

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Its given that Log x/ log y =log 4/log 3  so logy X= log3 4 and then can I conclude that y=3 and X=4

Comment: Is this correct

Comment: No, from "$log_y(X)= log_3(4)$" it does NOT follow that X= 4 and y= 3!  $In general you cannot determine two unknown values from one equation.

Comment: No, from "$log_y(X)= log_3(4)$" it does NOT follow that X= 4 and y= 3!  $log_3(4)= \frac{log_{10}(4)}{log_{10}(3)}= 1.26...$.  Saying that $log_y(X)= 1.26$ is, as I said before, the same as saying $X= y^{1.26}$.  So you can take y to be whatever number you like and set $X= y^{1.26}$.  For example, taking y= 5, $X= 5^{1.26}= 7.6$ approximately.  $log_{5}(7.6)= \frac{log(7.6)}{log(5)}= 1.26$.  In general you cannot determine two unknown values from one equation.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have $$\frac {\log x}{\log y} = \log _{y}x = \frac {3}{4}$$

The base of logarithm in this case is $10$ but you can have it in any other base as well.

For example  $$\frac {\ln x}{\ln y} = \log _{y}x = \frac {3}{4}$$
is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The way that "change of base" formula is derived is to use the fact that "$z= log_y(x)$" is equivalent to $x= y^z$.  So saying $log_y(x)= \frac{3}{4}$ is the same as saying $x= y^{3/4}$.  That, of course, is the same as $x^4= y^3$.  Now, taking the logarithm, to some base b, of both sides $log_b(x^4)= 4log_b(x)= log_b(y^3)= 3log_b(y)$.  From that, $\frac{log_b(x)}{log_b{y}}= \frac{3}{4}$.

To prove the other way, just reverse the above: From $\frac{log_b(x)}{log_b{y}}= \frac{3}{4}$ we have $log_b(x^4)= 4log_b(x)= log_b(y^3)= 3log_b(y)$ so that $x^4= y^3$, etc.

Comment: I have added a bit more to the question